# Show specific image of user from user id

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database named **login** and a table named **users**.

the **users** table has 6 rows (uid, image, username,password,firstname and lastname).

I want the image of the person logging in to show in a div. But it won't show up for some reason.

Here's the snippet of what I'm using:

**logindb.php**:

```
<?php
try {
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login', "root", "");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}

$uid = $_POST['username1'];
$pwd = $_POST['password1'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username1 AND `password` = :password1";
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$userData = [
'username1'=>$uid,
'password1'=>$pwd,
];

$statement->execute($userData);

if($statement->rowCount() > 0){
session_start();
$_SESSION['admin']= $uid;
$_SESSION['logged'] = true;
header('Location: indextemplate.php');
exit();
}

elseif(empty($uid&$pwd)){
header('Location: index1.php?error=empty1');
exit();
}
elseif ($uid!=$idvariable&$pwd!=$idvarible){
header('Location: index1.php?error=empty2');
exit();
}

?>
```

and here is where I want it to show:

```
 <!-- menu profile quick info -->
        <div class="profile clearfix">
          <div class="profile_pic">
              <?php
               $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login");
                $uid1 = $_SESSION['admin'];
                $users= "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `uid`='$uid1'";
                $data= mysqli_query($conn,$users) or die("Connection Failed!");
               while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 

                   $imgdata = $row['image'];?>

            <?php echo '<center><img src="'.$imgdata.'" alt="..." class="img-circle profile_img"></center>'; ?>

            <?php

               }      
              ?>
          </div>
          <div class="profile_info">
            <span>Welcome,</span>
            <h2><?php echo $_SESSION['admin'];

            ?></h2>
          </div>
        </div>
  <!-- /menu profile quick info -->
```

What am I doing wrong? When I put `$uid1 = $_SESSION['logged'];` it shows the image from the uid `1` even tho the uid currently logged in is `2`

**EDIT**:
Here's a  [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRTLR.png) of my database table

Comment: Add a screenshot of your database table

Comment: have you checked Session stores the same details?

Comment: _When I put $uid1 = $_SESSION['logged'];_ do you mean `$_SESSION['admin']` ?

Comment: @JigarShah When I put $uid = $_SESSION['admin'] no image appears but when I put `$uid1 = $_SESSION['logged'];` an image appears.

Comment: `$_SESSION['logged']` is Boolean and having value `true`  i.e. `1` so it will show image of user having uid `1` .  You need to check what `$_SESSION['admin']` contains. If you put static uid you will the value of other users as well.

Comment: @JigarShah I see. When I put `$_SESSION['admin']=3;` it changes shows the image of user number 3. I just need to find a way to set the session admin to the same uid of whoever logins.

Comment: check my answer below, found the reason ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are not getting the image is

```
$_SESSION['admin']= $uid; // should be uid, not username
```

you have assigned name in `$uid` and using in query to search as an `integer` value.

Comment: I found the mistake. It should be **$uiid = $_SESSION['admin'];** and **$users= "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$uiid'";**

Comment: yes, there was issue with your  session variable `admin`. you can accept the answer if you found useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","DbName"); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = $id";
$sth = $db->query($sql);
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';
```

As you are storing image in a database, this is the correct way to display Image.

Answer (score 0):

try with

$imgdata = $row['image'];

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $imgdata ).'"/>';
```